# Triply English or Triply American

Tags: knowledge, pattern

The following list of words divides evenly into two groups of words which I describe as **Triply English** and **Triply American**.

> American
>   Assault
>   Citation
>   Common
>   Count
>   Diamond
>   Fleet
>   Flying
>   Lord
>   More
>   Rock
>   Sand
>   Sir
>   Slew
>   War
>   West

**Can you tell me which words belong in each group?**
**Can you give a word which is both Triply English and Triply American?**

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> In horse racing, there is a distinction known as the Triple Crown of Thoroughbred Racing, rarely given for winning three prestigious horse races. Probably the most famous of these are the ones in the UK (2000 Guineas, The Derby, St. Leger) and the ones in the US (Kentucky, Preakness, and Belmont). (Being more familiar with the American horse names, Citation and Slew (for Seattle Slew) stood out to me.)
>
>  As it turns out, each word appears in one of the horses' names.
>
>  Triply American: **American** Pharoah, **Assault**, **Citation**, **Count** Fleet, Count **Fleet**, **Sir** Barton, Seattle **Slew**, **War** Admiral
>  Triply English: **Common**, **Diamond** Jubilee, **Flying** Fox, **Lord** Lyon, Galtee **More**, **Rock** Sand, Rock **Sand**, **West** Australian

Second question

> The only word that appears in both lists is **Fox** (Flying Fox for UK, Gallant Fox for US)

Answer (score 6):

Answer to the second question:

> "Fox"
>
>  1899 - "Flying Fox" (UK)
>
>  1930 - "Gallant Fox" (US)